# Spring Webflow for Grails 4

Tags: gradle, spring-webflow, grails-4

I am migrating from Grails 1.1 to Grails 4.0.11. we have used Spring Webflow in it, but it never works in Grails 4. Is there any solution to implement Spring Webflow in Grails4?

Answer (score 0):

[Here's](https://github.com/grails/grails-core/issues/601) an open issue about the situation of Spring Webflow in newest grails version. The plugin is broken since version 2.x and seems that will not have any kind of refactoring.